# ec2 server postgres error "version `GLIBC_2.14' not found"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, glibc, psql, libc

While trying to `\i create_db.sql` psql throws the error:

```
psql:create_db.sql:123: ERROR:  could not load library 
"/usr/lib64/pgsql/plpgsql.so": /lib64/libc.so.6: version 
`GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/lib64/pgsql/plpgsql.so)
```

Line 123 of create_db.sql is the last line of the file, at the end of a a function definition:

```
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Versions of stuff:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.7

$ /lib64/libc.so.6 --version
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.17, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7).
Compiled on a Linux 3.2.5 system on 2014-06-09.
Available extensions:
    The C stubs add-on version 2.1.2.
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
    RT using linux kernel aio
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>.
```

Do I need to have glibc exactly version 2.14 or should 2.17 work too?

Comment: What's the distro and version exactly - and what AMI? More importantly, how *exactly* did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: ...? Well? You've posted a question, do you want help?

Comment: Hi @CraigRinger, two years after this question was asked I'm having exactly the same problem. I'm running Amazon Linux AMI release 2012.03, postgres 9.1.5 and glibc 2.17. I'll open a bounty for that question.

Answer (score 7):

Your PostgreSQL install, or your OS install in general, is at least somewhat broken.

At a guess, you must've force-installed some RPM you found somewhere random instead of configuring repositories and using `yum install` to install PostgreSQL.

You don't need an exactly matching glibc version. It just has to declare that it's *compatible* with the required version by exposing a suitable `GLIBC_` symbol .

e.g. on my Fedora 20, with glibc 2.18, I'd have no problems running programs compiled for glibc 2.14 because:

```
$ /lib64/libc.so.6 --version
GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.18, by Roland McGrath et al.

$ nm /lib64/libc.so.6| grep GLIBC_2.14
0000000000000000 A GLIBC_2.14
```

my glibc declares that it's compatible with 2.14.

Comment: my glibc declares the same. Still, postgres doesn't run and in the logs I can see: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib64/pgsql/plperl.so": /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib64/libnsl.so.1)